# Migration can't get past changeset and stops running

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm migrating our local TFS to VSO using the OpsHub VSO migration utility.

It stopped migrating at a certain changeset and every time I restart the migration, it won't go any further and stops again after a while.

I've noticed one changeset is pending for retry, with the message "Error occurred while sync. GetAndDownloadFile :The server returned content type text/html, which is not supported."

I also do not have an option to skip this changeset.

How can I get it to continue again?

**EDIT: New issue:**

It now stopped at 6311 out of 9542 changesets with the message

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No matching items found in
>   $/Global Libraries/Release/Global Libraries 2.0.1/Global Libraries
>   2.0.1.sln at the specified version, or you do not have permission to access them. It seems changeset has items across team projects and all
>   such projects are not selected in configuration. Please create new
>   configuration selecting all such projects to allow processing of this
>   changeset.

What I make out of this is that I haven't selected all team projects used in this changeset.

However, when checking the changeset:
[image]
Only 2 team projects are part of this changeset and both were selected to migrate in this configuration.

Comment: Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location <c or d>:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com 
Also in current version there is one issue if single commit contains more than 41944 then few files are missed.
Can you verify this?
If so then we are providing new release in near future.

Comment: The logs are sent, but what do you mean by 'contains more than 41944'? 41944 what?

Comment: Meant more than 41944 files in a commit. In that case there is an error where some files are missed. The next release addresses this issue.

Comment: In that case, no we don't have any check-ins that contain than much files in one set.

Comment: Do you have any labels which have more than that many files (Labels are also changesets)

Comment: We have never used labels, only changesets

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs if your TFS instance has been upgraded from v2005/2008/2010. When you receive this error while using the migration tool, verify in your Event Log for more information pertaining to this.

Secondly, the utility will show you the changeset id for which is issue is occurring. Try to download this specific changeset through your Visual Studio Source Control Explorer and see what is the outcome.

Comment: TFS itself did gave the error on 2 files in an old check-in (about 3-4 years ago). I tried to rollback the check-in on those 2 files, since they are from an old release branch. The broken files are gone now, but the error keeps popping up in the tool. Tried to patch the TFS server with SP1 and specific Hotfixes, but those couldn't even install. Now trying to get the server up and running again, cause TFS won't start anymore.